# After Nvidia software crash computer is 3x faster?

Tags: graphics-card, performance, crash, speed, cuda

Around 30 minutes ago my nvidia software/cuda crashed and it opened my default browser to the support page for nvidia. It asked me to restart Adobe Premiere as the "CUDA renderer" was no longer available.

Ever since then, editing in Premiere has been 3x faster, rendering the same, browsing etc.. I always thought that for a 2000 $ laptop mine was quite slow, I just didn't realize until this crash how slow compared to how fast it apparently can be.

My fear is once I restart or shut down the laptop at any time it will revert back to the same sluggish pace. How can I ensure it stays in the state it is in now (as far as speed) despite restarting?

I have an MSI Ghost Pro 4k Laptop.

Comment: Try installing the most up-to-date nVidia drivers for the graphics card on your laptop. That may resolve your issue. It is doubtful that a restart or shut down would automagically make things slow, again.

Comment: It could be a problem with your drivers, as tab designworks outlined. Try disabling CUDA renderer into Adobe Premier and check if that fixes the problem after restarting. If it does, something is wrong with your nVidia card.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, however the crash has improved all (emphasis on all) of my activity, including browsing the web and navigating Windows. Not sure if just updating the drivers will fix that issue.